# Diferença entre file_get_contents e curl ?

Tags: php, libcurl, file-get-contents

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma diferença entre usar o cURL e file_get_contents e qual é mais seguro ?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Na verdade quase não tem relação nenhuma. São coisas completamente diferentes, mas como ambas podem ser usadas para acessar um URL (e isso depende da configuração do PHP permitir), voce pode em ALGUNS casos usar um ou o outro (mas isso é um caso específico).

Comment: Veja no próprio manual que a descrição da função não tem nada a ver com o que foi respondido até o momento: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar `file_get_contents` tem como finalidade ler o conteúdo de um arquivo. Mas **também pode ser usado** para ler urls.

No PHP, existem alguns Wrappers (uma definição parecida com o protocolo das requisições http), onde você pode definir que tipo de **stream** será lida por essas funções.

Por exemplo, com `file_get_contents`posso ler: dados na  memória, dados enviados via Http Post ou Put, arquivo de extensão RAR, e urls HTTP.

Para exemplificar, mostro abaixo como ler os dados enviados via POST ou PUT, numa requisição HTTP. Eles podem ser acessados pelo `file_get_contents` e outras funções de leitura de arquivos em PHP (`fopen` ou `readfile`).

Exemplo:

```
$raw_http_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Veja a lista de [Wrappers suportados pelo PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/wrappers.php).

Sendo assim, então é possível através do wrapper `http://` ou `https://` fazer requisições para urls. Isso não é limitado somente para requisições do tipo `GET`, como foi citado na outra resposta, mas para qualquer tipo de método de requisição HTTP, como `POST`, `PUT` e afins.

Nesse último caso, é necessário apenas adicionar um *context* (através da função `stream_context_create`) para a função de leitura onde você está lendo os dados de uma `url`.

Exemplo de requisição com `context`

```
// Desabilita a verificação de SSL

$config = array(
    "ssl"=> array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  

$context = stream_context_create($config);

file_get_contents("http://site.com.br/", false, $context);
```

## CURL

Segundo o manual do PHP:

> O PHP suporta libcurl, uma biblioteca criada por Daniel Stenberg, que permite que você conecte-se e comunique-se com diferentes tipos de servidores usando diferentes tipos de protocolos. libcurl atualmente dá suporte aos protocolos http, https, ftp, gopher, telnet, dict, file, e ldap. libcurl também suporta certificados HTTPS, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, upload via FTP (podendo também ser feito com a extensão ftp do PHP), upload HTTP por formulário, proxies, cookies, e autenticação com usuário e senha.

Ou seja, o curl contém como finalidade fazer requisições de diversos tipo. É amplamente usado para fazer requisições a protocolos http e https.

Ele, Diferentemente do `file_get_contents`, não suporta leitura de sistema arquivos do seu servidor. Esse é um bom ponto a se observar.

## Vantagens e Desvantagens

**Permissões para leitura de URLs**

Com o uso das funções de leitura de tipos de arquivo em PHP, é necessário que a diretiva `allow_url_open` esteja habilitada no seu `php.ini`. Sem 
isso você não conseguirá fazer essa operação.

Porém, como a extensão `curl` é preparada justamente para esse tipo de requisição não há restrições de leitura de `urls`.

**Requisições simultâneas**

Outro ponto importante de se destacar é que com `file_get_contents` você não consegue fazer requisições simultaneas, já com o [Curl é possível](http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/).

Vou explicar o que significa as requisições simultâneas.

Elas são essenciais para reduzir o tempo de processamento da sua página.

Suponhamos que ao fazer uma requisição a um script em PHP, você precisa fazer requisições para 5 outras páginas. Para cada url que você captura a requisição, é necessário esperar uma resposta para que a outra operação seja feita.

Com as requisições simultâneas, o `curl` internamente envia as requisições, sendo apenas necessário esperar que todas as respostas sejam concluídas.

Veja aqui [um exemplo de requisições múltiplas com Curl](http://php.net/curl_multi_init)

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents` para além de  [lêr todo o conteúdo de um arquivo para uma string](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php), muitas vezes também é usado para simples requisições a urls, apesar de a partir do php 4.3 conseguirmos também definir outros parametros da requisição quando estas são necessárias existe sempre tendência a usar `curl` em vez do parametro [context](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php) do `file_get_contents`

`curl` é uma ferramenta totalmente configurável, podemos definir todas as opções e mais alguma para uma dada requisição.

Quanto à segurança, o serviço/url a que vai ser feita a requisição, seja `curl` ou `file_get_contents` é que se tem de preocupar com isso. Mas para um simples pedido `GET`, basta definir que só um determinado `User-Agent` (ex: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1`) é que pode aceder para o DEFAULT `file_get_contents` já não resultar, aí há a tendência para usar `curl` e definir um `User-Agent` na requisição (apesar de com `file_get_contents` também ser possível, criando um stream e usando como [terceiro parametro](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) da função).

Exemplo de uma requisição/pedido `GET` com curl definindo um `User-Agent`:

```
function get_req($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $return;
}
```

E usamos assim:

```
echo get_req('http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134738/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-file-get-contents-e-curl');
```

No meu caso, para `GET` simples experimento sempre primeiro `file_get_contents` (simplesmente por redução de código), caso retorne algum resultado inesperado aí eu oriento-me usando `curl`.

Comment: Segundo o site php.net o `file_get_contents` também efetua requisição do tipo `POST` ... com as configuração feitas para `stream_context_create`.

Comment: Tem razão, deve ter acontecido nas ultimas versões do php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents

Comment: Vlw Miguel, consegui entender.  Como o @João disse, o file_get_contents também aceita post, mas consegui entender entre usar um e o outro.

Comment: Na realidade, as pessoas tendem a usar `curl` (pois mesmo assim há mais opções). Vou editar a resposta corretamente

Comment: @Miguel só não dei pontuação ainda por causa disso, olha só desde a versão (PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5, PHP 7) já tem esse recurso. Concordo em usar o curl mas, se fizer uma afirmação dessa alguém pode te bulgar na resposta! kkkk

Comment: file_get_contents abre qualquer tipo de arquivo e ainda os stream suportados pelo PHP. O início da resposta parece levar a pessoa entender uma informação de forma errada

Comment: Tem razão, como eu já uso php muito antes disso, não conhecia esses parametros novos da função

Comment: file_gets_content() e tipo uma implementação do curl no php

Comment: @NikoBellic nem perto disso. É apenas uma função para ler conteúdo de um arquivo/stream e por acaso, acessa URLs DEPENDENDO de como o PHP foi configurado.

Comment: Eu posso ate esta equivocado @Bacco mas qual e o URL que não referencia algum arquivo?

Comment: @NikoBellic é essencial que você não confunda sistemas de arquivos com conexões remotas ou algo do tipo. A url é uma referência a um arquivo remoto (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP). Quando você usa um `path` (caminho) o file_get_contents vai ler o arquivo no seu servidor (não como se tivesse lendo uma "url interna", mas sim o arquivo que está no disco)

Comment: @NikoBellic URL não referencia arquivo nenhum. Se "por acaso" o servidor do URL pegar um arquivo, é particularidade da implementação. Eu posso muito bem chamar um meusite.com/batata.jpg, e não existir nenhum arquivo com esse nome na máquina, e mesmo assim, você receber uma imagem. Não é pq dois eventos costumam acontecer juntos que signifique que um é conectado ao outro.

Comment: nada convencente este seu comentário @Wallace

Comment: @NikoBellic tenho bastante experiência com PHP.  Sei que eu não estou fazendo um comentário irresponsável. Você parece estar confundindo sistema de arquivos com requisições http e etc. `file_get_contents` quando você usa um "caminho" não significa que está fazendo uma "url relativa", você está literalmente lendo um arquivo no disco. Se fosse no Windows por exemplo, isso funcionaria perfeitamente: `file_get_contents('c:\\temp.txt')`, porém você consegue fazer isso acessando uma url? Não. São duas coisas distintas, talvez confusas pois o php resolveu tratar tudo na mesma função.