# Webservice de CNPJ

Tags: php, web-service, get

Estou precisando pegar uns dados de CNPJ pro meu sistema de cadastro, achei esse webservice na interwebs.

GET - http://receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/[cnpj]

Mas não estou conseguindo implementar no código PHP.

Vcs poderiam me ajudar?

Desculpe pessoal,

Segue minha tentativa de implementar:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CNPJ</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- Adicionando JQuery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Adicionando Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function() {

        function limpa_formulário_cnpj() {
            // Limpa valores do formulário de cnpj.
            $("#rua").val("");
            $("#bairro").val("");
            $("#cidade").val("");
            $("#uf").val("");
            $("#nome").val("");
        }

        //Quando o campo cnpj perde o foco.
        $("#cnpj").blur(function() {

            //Nova variável "cnpj" somente com dígitos.
            var cnpj = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');

            //Verifica se campo cnpj possui valor informado.
            if (cnpj != "") {

                //Expressão regular para validar o CNPJ.
                var validacnpj = /^[0-9]/;

                //Valida o formato do CNPJ.
                if(validacnpj.test(cnpj)) {

                    //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
                    $("#logradouro").val("...")
                    $("#bairro").val("...")
                    $("#municipio").val("...")
                    $("#uf").val("...")
                    $("#nome").val("...")

                    $.getJSON("http://receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/"+ cnpj, function(dados) {

                        if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                            //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
                            $("#logradouro").val(dados.logradouro);
                            $("#bairro").val(dados.bairro);
                            $("#municipio").val(dados.municipio);
                            $("#uf").val(dados.uf);
                            $("#nome").val(dados.abertura);
                        } //end if.
                        else {
                            //Cnpj pesquisado não foi encontrado.
                            limpa_formulário_cnpj();
                            alert("CNPJ não encontrado.");
                        }
                    });
                } //end if.
                else {
                    //cnpj é inválido.
                    limpa_formulário_cnpj();
                    alert("Formato de CNPJ inválido.");
                }
            } //end if.
            else {
                //cnpj sem valor, limpa formulário.
                limpa_formulário_cnpj();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Inicio do formulario -->
  <form method="get" action=".">
    <label>Cnpj:
    <input name="cnpj" type="text" id="cnpj" value="" size="10" maxlength="19" /></label><br />
    <label>Rua:
    <input name="logradouro" type="text" id="logradouro" size="60" /></label><br />
    <label>Bairro:
    <input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Cidade:
    <input name="municipio" type="text" id="municipio" size="40" /></label><br />
    <label>Estado:
    <input name="uf" type="text" id="uf" size="2" /></label><br />
    <label>Nome:
    <input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" size="8" /></label><br />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pessoal, editei a pergunta! Não sabia das "regras"...

Comment: Não é pelas regras, melhorou bastante com a edição. É mais pelo fato de do jeito que estava ficar impraticável te ajudar. Já com a postagem nova, dá pra perceber que se trata de um problema de CORS. O Javascript não vai conseguir pegar os dados vindo de outro dominio. Teria que usar o PHP mesmo para obter os dados. Notei que vc usou a tag PHP, mas de fato está usando jQuery atualmente. Se estiver de fato usando PHP no seu servidor, fica mais fácil.

Comment: @Bacco Isso, eu pretendo colocar em um servidor PHP.
Mas preciso que essa comunicação seja "automática"! Fiz esse mesmo script no Via CEP e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Cuidado com o "funcionou perfeitamente", em condições reais a coisa muda.

Comment: conseguiu fazer a implementação?

Answer (score 2):

Como a pergunta pede em `PHP`, irei responder com essa, caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida...

No *PHP* você tem duas opções para baixar conteúdo da web. Você pode utilizar tanto a função [**file_get_contents**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) quanto [**cURL**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php)

Com o *PHP* você não terá problemas com `Cross-Origin`, mas poderá ter problemas de bloqueio devido ao *Header*, mas a depender do caso, é possível utilizar mesmo assim.

A função `file_get_contents` foi criada para ler dados de entrada, arquivos etc. Porém, você pode utiliza-la para requisições também.

```
<?php

$cnpj = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "cnpj", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if (empty($cnpj)) die("Informe um CNPJ");

echo file_get_contents("http://receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/{$cnpj}");
```

Já a função `cURL`, ela é uma "extensão" que se conecta com [**libcurl**](https://curl.haxx.se/). Essa biblioteca permite que você faça requisições com diversos protocolos, entre eles: *https*, *ftp*, *gopher*, *telnet* etc.

```
<?php

$cnpj = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "cnpj", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if (empty($cnpj)) die("Informe um CNPJ");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    /* Define URL */
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/{$cnpj}",

    /* Informa que você quer o retorno */
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

    /**
     * (Opcional)
     * Como há limitações para acessar a URL acima,
     * Você pode utilziar proxies para evitar isso.
     */
]);

/* Acessa URL e captura o retorno */
$response = curl_exec($ch);

/* Fecha a conexão */
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

> Para saber mais sobre ambos, deixo como dica a pergunta [Diferença entre file_get_contents e curl?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134738/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-file-get-contents-e-curl)

Para acessar através do `JavaScript`, basta utilizar `XMLHttpRequest` ou similar.

```
$.getJSON("consulta_cnpj.php?cnpj="+ cnpj, function(dados) {

    if (!("erro" in dados)) {
        $("#logradouro").val(dados.logradouro);
        $("#bairro").val(dados.bairro);
        $("#municipio").val(dados.municipio);
        $("#uf").val(dados.uf);
        $("#nome").val(dados.abertura);
    else {
        alert("CNPJ não encontrado.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está fazendo uma requisição Cross-Origin. Isso significa que seu domínio está tentando acessar via Cliente outro Domínio, o que não é permitido normalmente.

Para resolver seu problema você tem duas formas:

1 - Usar uma API que já permite isto, como o https://www.hubdodesenvolvedor.com.br/detalhes/cnpj

2 - Usar um Proxy de acesso que faz o Cross Origin, como o https://crossorigin.me/ ou https://enable-cors.org/.

Como ficaria isto:

```
$.getJSON("https://crossorigin.me/http://receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/"+ cnpj, function(dados)
```

Answer (score 0):

O segredo aqui é o getJSON nao pegar direto da receita: `$.getJSON("http://receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/"+ cnpj, function(dados)`
mas sim criar um arquivo que crie um JSON  e ai sim pegar os dados dele:
`$.getJSON("pegaCNPJ.php?cnpj="+ cnpj, function(dados)`

Deve ser JSON valido. Veja o meu:

`{ 
  "atividade_principal": "Aluguel de outras máquinas e equipamentos comerciais e industriais não especificados anteriormente, sem operador",
  "fantasia": "CALPHER",
  "nome": "CAXR MAQXAS E EQUXNTOS LTDA",
  "cnpj": "11.036.404/9991-04",
  "logradouro": "R ALFREDO ACHCAR,",
  "numero": "XXXX-A",
  "complemento": "EDIF: X;",
  "bairro": "NOVA VILA",
  "municipio": "CAFUNDO",
  "uf": "SP",
  "cep": "XX.XX0-000",
  "telefone": "(19) XXXX-6XXX / (19) XXX9-XXX2",
  "email": "xxxxxxxxxx@uol.com.br",
  "status": "OK" 
}`