# Qual a melhor forma para pegar o conteúdo dentro de uma div para uma variável?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Entou necessitando pegar o conteudo de uma div para minha varivel para que eu possa tratar ela e fazer meu envio de email.

Estou tentando com JS porém está me retornando erro "undefined", meu codigo está dessa forma:

```
var pegarTxt = document.getElementById("Total").text;
document.getElementById('TotalFinaliz').innerHTML = pegarTxt;
```

Onde estou errando, porque aparentemente a logica está correta, lembrando onde estou tentando exibir fica invisível e só mostra após tudo estar correto.

Gostaria de saber também se é possível puxar o conteudo da div via php sem ter que usar o file_get_contents, pois acho que isso iria deixar mais lento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionando o conteúdo a um campo de entrada antes de enviá-lo

```js
    var pegarTxt = document.getElementById("Total").innerText;
    //para textarea
    document.getElementById('TotalFinaliz').value = pegarTxt;
    document.getElementById('TotalFinaliz2').innerText = pegarTxt;
    document.getElementById('TotalFinaliz3').innerHTML = pegarTxt;

    var pegarTxt = document.querySelector('div').textContent;
    document.getElementById('TotalFinaliz4').innerHTML = pegarTxt;

    //para input somente .value
    document.getElementById('TotalFinaliz5').value = pegarTxt;
```

```html
    <div id="Total">Entou necessitando pegar o conteudo de uma div para minha varivel para que eu possa tratar ela e fazer meu envio de email</div>

    <textarea id="TotalFinaliz"></textarea>
    
    <textarea id="TotalFinaliz2"></textarea>
    
    <textarea id="TotalFinaliz3"></textarea>

    <textarea id="TotalFinaliz4"></textarea>

    <input id="TotalFinaliz5">
```

```js
var pegarTxt = document.getElementById("Total").innerText;

//no textarea de indice 2
document.getElementsByClassName("RonaldoM")[2].innerText = pegarTxt;
```

```html
<textarea class="RonaldoM"></textarea>
<textarea class="RonaldoM"></textarea>
<textarea class="RonaldoM"></textarea>

<div id="Total">Entou necessitando pegar o conteudo de uma div para minha varivel para que eu possa tratar ela e fazer meu envio de email</div>
```

> Há muitos servidores que não permitem que se utilize a função file_get_contents(). Para esses casos, é possível colocar numa variável alguma página externa utilizando a biblioteca [cURL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php)

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://exemplo.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$conteudo = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

O conteúdo da página  estará na variável $conteudo.
```

> `file_get_contents` tem a finalidade de ler arquivos, e por acaso também acessar Urls, já a biblioteca cURL tem por finalidade uma conexão direta com uma página da web, seja ela interna ao seu domínio, ou mesmo, externa. Então por este motivo eu acredito ser melhor o uso do `cUrl`

[**Diferença entre file_get_contents e curl**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134738/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-file-get-contents-e-curl)

Comment: Funcionou aqui, obrigado !

Answer (score 2):

A forma correta de recuperar o conteúdo "renderizado" é utilizando a propriedade [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)

#### Exemplo

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p').innerText;
console.log(p);
```

```html
<p>Stackoverflow Português</p>
```

Também exite uma alternativa similar, que é a propriedade [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), mas vale ressaltar que existe diferenças significativas entre as duas, conforme [informado na documentação.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

#### Exemplo

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p').textContent;
console.log(p);
```

```html
<p>Stackoverflow Português</p>
```

#### Referências

- [Node.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)
- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, já foi solucionado